# Swap contents from two different lists by clicking on both list items

Tags: jquery, list, onclick, swap, items

I want to swap elements from two different lists. So if I select something on the left list and on the right list they need to swap.

It currently looks like this:
Html:

```
<ul id="sortable1" class="connectedSortable">
    <li value="1" class="ui-state-default">Sort1 Item 1</li>
    <li value="2" class="ui-state-default">Sort1 Item 2</li>
    <li value="3" class="ui-state-default">Sort1 Item 3</li>
    <li value="4" class="ui-state-default">Sort1 Item 4</li>
    <li value="5" class="ui-state-default">Sort1 Item 5</li>
</ul>

<ul id="sortable2" class="connectedSortable">
    <li value="1" class="ui-state-highlight">Sort2 Item 1</li>
    <li value="2" class="ui-state-highlight">Sort2 Item 2</li>
    <li value="3" class="ui-state-highlight">Sort2 Item 3</li>
    <li value="4" class="ui-state-highlight">Sort2 Item 4</li>
    <li value="5" class="ui-state-highlight">Sort2 Item 5</li>
</ul>
```

Jquery:

```
var testClickSort1 ='';
var testClickSort2 ='';

$(function() {
    $("#sortable1").sortable({
        cursor: 'pointer',
        connectWith: ".connectedSortable"
    }).disableSelection();

$("#sortable2").sortable({
    cursor: 'pointer',
    connectWith: ".connectedSortable"
}).disableSelection();

$("#sortable1 li").on('click',function(){
       // $("#testClickSort1").html($(this).attr('value'));
        testClickSort1 = $(this).attr('value'); 
        test();
});

$("#sortable2 li").on('click',function(){
       // $("#testClickSort2").html($(this).attr('value'));
        testClickSort2 = $(this).attr('value');
        test();
});
});

 function test(){ 
      if ((testClickSort1 != "") && (testClickSort2 != "")) {
         alert ("test: " + testClickSort1 + '' +  testClickSort2);
         //function to swap testclicksort1 with testclicksort2
         testClickSort1 = '';
         testClickSort2 = '';
}   
}
```

It can be viewed here:

http://jsfiddle.net/qkCcS/26/

Now I need to know what the function is to swap testclicksort1 with testclicksort2.

Thanks in advance.

Greets,

Wouter

Comment: Completely renewed my code. Making some progress!

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `>` immediate descendant selector. Also I would recommend you to use [.data()](http://api.jquery.com/data/) instead of [.attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)

Instead of

```
 $("ul.icecream>li.active")
```

Use

```
 $("ul.icecream li.active")
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/ZVJja/)

Compete Code

```
function swap(){
    if($("ul.icecream>li").hasClass("active")){
        var p1_name = $("ul.icecream li.active").data("name");
        var p_name = $(this).data("name");
        $(this).data("name", p1_name).text(p1_name);
        $("ul.icecream li.active").data("name", p_name).text(p_name).removeClass("active");
    }
    else{
        $(this).addClass("active");
    }
}
$("ul.icecream>li").on("click", swap);
```

Comment: Thanks for the improvements! Still I would like to know how to get two separate unordered lists instead of one. Since I need to style the other list completely different.